# I installed Ubuntu on my Local drive (F:) instead of my USB while trying to dual boot windows and Ubuntu (SOLVED)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, iso

Sooo i might have accidentally clicked "drive (F)" which is my harddrive instead of (D:) which is my USB stick while using universal usb installer
Thus formatting my (F) drive into "uui"
And not partitioning properly
Now my harddrive boot doesn't work

After Using Ubuntu live and then using windows recovery on a USB stick to see my files they all seem to be okay

Now my question is "is there a way to restore windows without deleting my data?"

If no then
Is it Safe (as in will my device still work)  to just burn windows official ISO into a USB stick and use it to reinstall windows?

(Alternatively is it safe to install Ubuntu and dual boot windows from there?)

Note : I don't know why but my drives now have different names ,my (C:) is now (F:) and my (F:) is now (C:) and my (E:) is now (G:) i don't know what this means, should i be worried?

Im using an asus laptop

Edit: i burned Gparted into a USB booted it and found out that my hard drive was using my (F:) drive to boot windows
I right clicked it > manage flags > untic the "boot" box > put the boot flag on the drive that says "system reserved"
Now it runs fine and im using the official Ubuntu iso from the website to install Ubuntu on a unallocated space instead of universal usb installer
Thanks

Comment: If the drive is large enough, you may install Ubuntu there and dual boot. Also, additional about 512MB partition for EFI will be needed.

Comment: Also in Live Environment, use GParted to get the idea of drives in `sdXY`s. This will help you in structuring your partition table as to your need.

Comment: You need to use Windows tools to repair Windows which is beyond this site. Drives often change order when you plug in a flash drive. But Windows only sees c: drive partition as the one it boots from. To understand where everything is installed when you have multiple drives and or installs by reviewing this report. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version over somewhat older ISO with your USB installer  or any working install.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: UUI does not generally overwrite hard drives unless you have checked the 'Show all Drives' box. Since you can see your Windows files they have not been overwritten. Unplug your Windows drive and try to install Ubuntu again. If it works, plug in your Windows drive and boot Ubuntu, then run `sudo update-grub` to add Windows to your boot menu.